# Wordpress / Woocommerce Variations Limit

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As many of you may know that there is a limit of product variations to 50 per product.

Does anyone know if this can be changed if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this maybe your problem please take a look at the woothemes documentation: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/problems-with-large-amounts-of-data-not-saving-variations-rates-etc/

Answer (score 2):

You can change it by adding the following code to functions.php (example shows the increase in the number of variations to 150):

```
define( 'WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS', 150 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a really [simple plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/increase-product-variation-limit-for-woocommerce/) for this.
It uses the hook `woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold`, [see docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-limit-on-number-of-variations-for-dynamic-variable-product-dropdowns/).